# EC2 Instance Freezes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose, unexpected-shutdown

I am experiencing sudden freezes in one particular instance.
Here some details of the instance:
Type: t2.micro
Region/av. zone: us-west-2b
OS: amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20180811-x86_64-gp2 (ami-a0cfeed8)

My this Ec2 instance freezes automatically.
 
I have docker installed in the instance.
I am new in this field.
don't have an idea from where can I get system or server log that why my ec2 instance continuously freezing, so that I can trace the problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Chances are you're running out of CPU credits, as `t2.micro` is a "burstable" instance type. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html

Comment: Could be EBS credits as well https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/understanding-burst-vs-baseline-performance-with-amazon-rds-and-gp2/

Comment: How do you know it’s freezing? Being it’s a virtual server, it takes a little more effort to determine if a server is “frozen.” Just wondering how you know?

Comment: Hi Ashok, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Comment: @Appleoddity I am accessing that using putty and putty console freezed.even when i tried to reconnect again, i am not able to connect so i thought that aws instance was freezed.

Comment: View profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning - reduction of pauses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of options:

1. Use a **larger size**, e.g. `t2.small` or `t2.medium` - if the freezing goes away it may be memory-related.
2. Examine [**CPU Credits**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-monitoring-cpu-credits.html) usage - if it "freezes" when the CPU credits go low you're overloading the instance. Use a larger one.
3. Examine the **OS logs** - in `/var/log/*`. There may be some clues about memory or other problems.
4. Once it "freezes" go to EC2 -> Instances -> Actions -> Instance Settings -> **Get System Log** and see if you get any clues there.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you @mlu https://serverfault.com/users/122588/mlu

Comment: Get System Log now is under Monitor and Troubleshoot menu

Answer (score 1):

Mine runs out of memory causing the CPU to spike to 100% killing processes along the way (e.g. Apache / MySQL)

Login to console.aws.amazon.com, to view your EC2 logs

1. Select the instance
2. Choose "Actions > Monitor and Troubleshoot > Get Instance Screenshot"

Hope this helps.